# How to properly set JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, java-home

I am trying to add JAVA_HOME system-wide and also add JAVA_HOME/bin to PATH (Ubuntu 12.04). If I add the following 2 lines at the end of /etc/environment, I cannot  login anymore afterwards. If I add the 2 lines to /etc/profile everything works. Wheres the problem?

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

There is already the following line in /etc/environment (line 1):

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

Answer (score 17):

Just write

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
```

on your /etc/environment, without the "export"

Comment: Why the double quotes?  Isn't it enough to write `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre`?

Answer (score 14):

`/etc/environment` is supposed to contain a set of environment variables given as key=value pairs. It is not a shell script, so you can't use shell commands such as `export` in it.