# How to config Java 9 in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-9

JDK 9 reached yesterday，and I downloaded the jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz.

directory

```
xx@xx:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-9$ ls

bin  conf  include  jmods  legal  lib README.html  release
```

It and java8 are very different.
I like to configure the same as java8,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25  
export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre  
export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:${JRE_HOME}/lib  
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

But java9 has no jre.
So I configured it like that (Add these in the .bashrc file)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9 
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and run source ~/.bashrc

But java version is still no change.
My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: Can you share the value of your $PATH? (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: You should ask this question in the ubuntu site.

Comment: You cna follow https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-linux-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-19D58769-FD72-4353-A935-40FCD82A7A81.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov  /usr/lib/jvm/java-9/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin

Comment: @Frank.Dai you shall update the PATH since it still reads jdk8.

Comment: @nullpointer  yes，you are right.

Comment: @Frank.Dai If this is solved by you now?

Comment: @nullpointer  yes

Comment: @Frank.Dai You need to accept correct answer to let everyone know.

Comment: @Ravi The correct answer in the comment,like nullpointer said.I updated the PATH to read jdk9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation and Configuration of JDK9 is step by step given below:

### Install JDK9 in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

### Make it as default:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-set-default
```

Changed in .bashrc, /etc/environment and also set default using

3 sections to change java configuration.

### .bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

### /ect/environment:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle"
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then run the following command and set

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Then run the command

```
source /etc/environment
```

### Check in terminal:

```
java -version
echo $JAVA_HOME
which java
which javac
```

### Issue#1:

Execute "source /etc/environment" in every shell where you want the variables to be updated:

```
$ source /etc/environment
```

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994031

### Issue#2:

Just write `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle"`
on your `/etc/environment`, without the "export"

/etc/environment is supposed to contain a set of environment variables given as key=value pairs. It is not a shell script, so you can't use shell commands such as export in it.

### Resource Link:

[How to properly set JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183934/how-to-properly-set-java-home-in-etc-environment)

### Issue#3:

To check if java is properly installed:

> ```
> $ which java
>
> $ which javac
> ```

You should get similar output:

/usr/bin/java

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23124805

### Issue#4:

To remove Oracle JDK completely, run the commands below:

### Completely remove criteria:

```
sudo apt-get remove oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove oracle-java9-installer
```

### Resource Link:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/tomcat7?action=remove

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have already solved it.The solution was discussed in comments, and I updated the PATH.Hope your answer can help others.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start with the setting up Java, you will need remove the OpenJDK/JRE from the system

Download jdk from oracle

then extract wit command `sudo tar -xvf ....`

Add the following system variables to end of /etc/profile file

```
JAVA_HOME=<Directory where JAVA has been extracted>/jdk1.8.0

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Now reload environment using command,

```
. /etc/profile
```

Copy-paste below lines into command prompt.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "<Directory where JAVA has been extracted>/bin/java" 1 

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "<Directory where JAVA has been extracted>/bin/javac" 1
```

Tell Ubuntu that our installation i.e., jdk1.8.0_05 must be the default Java.

Use below commands to do this-

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java <Directory where JAVA has been extracted>/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javac <Directory where JAVA has been extracted>/bin/javac

sudo update-alternatives --set javaws <Directory where JAVA has been extracted>/bin/javaws
```

Answer (score 1):

To install `Java 9` on `Ubuntu` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

To configure, you need to install `oracle-java9-set-default` package to make `Java 9` default version.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-set-default
```

Similarly, you can install `Java 9` using `--no-install-recommends`, then `Java 9` won't be set as your default version.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends oracle-java9-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it fully in command line:

1. `apt update`
2. `apt install -y curl`
3. `curl -jkL -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9+181/jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -o jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
4. `tar xvzf jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -C /opt/`
5. `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk-9/bin/java 100`
6. `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk-9/bin/javac 100`
7. `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jshell jshell /opt/jdk-9/bin/jshell 100`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this:

```
apt-get install python-software-properties software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
apt-get install oracle-java9-set-default
```